# Scaling delay values in Design compiler topographical

Tags: vlsi

I want to scale delay values in TLU plus file to zero . How can we achieve that in design compiler topographical mode. How can we scale delay values to zero of TLU plus file in DC topo

Answer (score 0):

Check "Assessing Design and Constraint Feasibility in Mapped Designs" on User Guide.
You can use:

```
   set_zero_interconnect_delay_mode true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).